# Facebook "Like" on iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, facebook, ipad

Has anyone implemented facebook "Like" on iPhone/iPad?
I've done general Facebook Connect implementation before, but it appears they're phasing that out in favour of OAuth and the Graph API?

We're trying to give users the ability to "Like" items of content in the app. Each item of content has a corresponding URL for its representation on the website.

Will it be possible to implement this kind of functionality (without implementing anything on the server side)?
And is there a library that will let us do this easily?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook will release an Open Graph API/SDK for iPhone to replace Facebook Connect.

Comment: Do you know if there's any timeline on this? Because our timeline is 1 week...

Probably shouldn't have said we could do this without first checking it out :)

Comment: Never heard any date from Facebook. My guess is they probably wanna wait for iPhone OS 4 out first. iPhone OS 4 will probably release before or during WWDC which starts June 7.

Answer (score -1):

If still relevant, our company has build native "like" and "share this" buttons for both iPhone and Android and it works to both Facebook and Twitter. You can check it out here:

[www.pinkelstar.com](http://www.pinkelstar.com)

We're coming out of Beta now. The libraries will be downloadable shortly.